# How systemd sets the initial date on the system?

Tags: systemd

How systemd sets the initial system date?

I have an embedded system with systemd configured as service manager. Initially, system is not connected to WiFi, RTC is not initialized.

When I boot the system, I see:

```
~# timedatectl 
                      Local time: Tue 2020-07-14 19:19:34 UTC
                  Universal time: Tue 2020-07-14 19:19:34 UTC
                        RTC time: Thu 1970-01-01 02:06:42
                       Time zone: n/a (UTC, +0000)
       System clock synchronized: no
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Where systemd takes `Tue 2020-07-14 19:19:34 UTC`? There is no previous journal logs in the system, and no `/var/lib/private/systemd/timesync/clock`.

Could please someone clarify? Thanks!

Comment: By take `Tue 2020-07-14 19:19:34 UTC` you mean the timezone that was used or how it calculates the hour itself?

Comment: @IdoHLevi Not the timezone. Year, month, day and time, how it calculates them initially, when NTP is not yet available.

Answer (score 2):

Lennart Poettering answered my question in systemd-devel@lists.freedesktop.org:

> It's configurable via the "time-epoch" meson variable at build
> time. If you don't specify it, the SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH env var is used
> (defined by the reproducible build folks). If that's not set, then
> it's the date of the latest git tag in the history of your git
> checkout, and if the sources didn't come via git but as tarball or so,
> it's the timestamp of the NEWS file.

> Or in other words: it's typically the build time of the package, or
> the time the release of systemd was done.

Answer (score 0):

The RTC is what time the actual bios thinks it is, if it was never being set - both manually or using NTP - it'll be whatever the factory has set, in your case it seems to be 0 (unix time starts from 1/1/1970)