# 'hwclock' and 'timedatectl' behaviour on the system with removed RTC battery

Tags: linux, time, embedded-linux, hwclock

I have embedded Linux running on device with the following setup:

- RTC battery is removed,
- No NTP server configured,
- With the following related defconfig:

  CONFIG_RTC_HCTOSYS=y

  CONFIG_RTC_SYSTOHC=y

After system boots up, I issue the commands:

```
$hwclock

hwclock: ioctl(RTC_RD_TIME) to /dev/rtc0 to read the time failed: Invalid argument


$timedatectl
Failed to query server: Failed to read RTC: Invalid argument

$date
Wed Mar 24 11:26:45 CET 2021
```

All commands return errors, except 'date' which returns some old date/time.

But after I sync hwclock with the system time:

```
$hwclock -w
```

all three commands start to work without errors and show the same date/time as'date' showed above,

before 'hwclock -w' sync.

Could you please clarify the following moments about this test:

1. From what source does 'date' take that old date/time value?
2. How does 'hwclock -w' sync help to resolve the errors returned by the commands?

   I initially  thought that 'hwclock -w' should sync with the value returned by 'timedatectl'.

   But since 'timedatectl' is in error condition, it looks like 'hwclock -w' takes time from the some other source,

   probably the same as 'date'.
3. Is there a way to configure 'timedatectl' to behave like 'date' when RTC battery is removed

   (i.e. to return some date/time value instead of an error) without the need to make 'hwclock -w' sync for it?

Comment: What init framework is used in your embedded system? Systemd, system V, OpenWRT procd? Usually fallback for initial system time is taken from root filesystem metadata, i.e. time when filesystem was last modified (or built if it is read only).

Comment: @dimich, systemd is used.

Comment: Probably the answer related to your first question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70524544/how-systemd-sets-the-initial-date-on-the-system).

Comment: @dimich, Yes, it explains the behaviour. Thank you.